# How to read word document story which is already open?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-addins

I have created a Word add-in. I want to read an active word document which is currently open(Content of word document story) by pressing a button which is on window form, and window form get open by click on the button from the ribbon. So let me be clear that how flow happens.

Ribbon -> Button on Ribbon (click it) -> A window form open (Having a button to read active document content) -> Reads the document.

I have tried to access document content by `WordOpenXML` property and the second method I've tried is to access paragraphs of the active document.

Try 1: Accessing paragraphs

```
private async Task<bool> SaveDocToCryptacomm1(string fileName)
{
    [...some code here...]

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    long paraCount = application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count;
    while (i < paraCount) {
        sb.Append(application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs[i].Range.Text);
    }

    [...some code here...]
}
```

Try 2: Accessing content from WordOpenXML property.

```
private async Task<bool> SaveDocToCryptacomm1(string fileName)
{
    [...some code here...]

    Encoding.Default.GetBytes(application.ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML);

    [...some code here...]
}
```

**Result of Try 1:**

Document get saved successfully but no content is there.

**Result of Try 2:**

Document get saved successfully but when I try to open it, it is corrupted.

In this case, what should i do, to read active document from Window form button click event.

Does the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application.ActiveDocument` will work? Am I doing something wrong or what?

**Edit:** Need to do this, without saving open document on local drive and Provided code I have written on Window form's button click event. Will it work?

Comment: If the activedocument is attached to the same instance of Word as the addin then it should be something like Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.

Comment: Indeed it is attached with same instance, let me do the same as you have asked for.

Comment: @Freeflow first of all sorry for late reply, and thank you for you reply. That line made my day. It worked. Thank you :)